# Can I start a VirtualBox server by shelling in remotely, whether by VBoxManage or otherwise?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, virtualbox

I've seen a couple of answers suggesting that some command like `VBoxManage <name of machine>` can start a VM from the command line. I saw reference to Windows and a path to `VBoxManage.exe`, but I'm interested from Mac.

Does this work both from a graphical and remote (`ssh`, etc.) command-line environment? If I open an `ssh` connection to a Mac that does not have anyone logged in graphically, is there any command that will start a server listening on various ports that, as far as servers listening, would have the same effect as if I had opened up VirtualBox graphically and started the server?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered at https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=84419 .

The command I think I wanted is `VBoxManage startvm <name of machine> --type headless`.

Thanks,